# Granting access to the Job Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I'm trying to grant access to the `Job Activity Monitor`. On my model office server I can create a new login and add it to the `SQLAgentReaderRole` role in msdb, and the id has access to the monitor. However in my production environment the exact same process gives me the following error:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Both are 2008 R2, but production is SP2, and MO is SP3. I'm making the assumption this doesn't matter but I could be wrong.

I checked and the associated permissions (`SQLAgentReaderRole`, `SQLAgentUserRole`, `PUBLIC in msdb and master`) and they appear to be the same.

Comment: The answer can be found in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641261/user-access-to-sql-server-agent-job-activity-monitor

Comment: @SQLStad Except that the reader role works fine on one instance but not the other.

Answer (score 4):

In order to give some privileged users access to `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs` we did the following.

1. Create a Database Role in `master` named something like `SQLAgentJobManager`.
2. Granted that role `EXECUTE` rights on `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs`.

Then via Logins or a Domain group, granted users a membership in the `SQLAgentJobManager` role in `master`.

**EDIT:** The way we implement this permission is through Domain Group login(s) such as (`SQLAgentJobManagerGroup`). Then add the group login to `master`'s `SQLAgentJobManager` role (for running `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs`) and to `msdb`'s `SQLAgentReaderRole` or `SQLAgentUserRole`.

After that we always add or remove logins from the `SQLAgentJobManagerGroup` to control the group membership for those rights.

Comment: I may have to go that route.  I was hoping to avoid it.  Mostly at this point I want to figure out why on earth it works on one instance but not another.

Comment: Is your other instance an older edition that was upgraded in place sometime ago?

Comment: Nope.  Both are fresh installs (well awhile ago anyway).

Comment: Are the trustworthy settings the same on both servers?

Comment: Yes.  msdb and all of the system databases have the same (default) settings.  msdb is trustworthy and the other three are not.